# Regular expression code for Racket vs Java vs sed (linux)

Tags: regex, scheme, racket

Do the code language of regular expressions in Racket similar or same as that of Java and of sed (linux utility)? Can the patterns used in one be used in other languages also? Are there any regex standards that can be used independent of platform?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A RegEx flavor may provide a narrower syntax from one another or lacks features in comparison to some other extended RegExes of other engines. Racket - which I'm not familiar with - states two different built-in procedures ***regexp** and ***pregexp**, first one is more compatible with egrep and the second is more Perl style.

> The regexp and byte-regexp procedures convert a string or byte string
>   (respectively) into a regexp value using a syntax of regular
>   expressions that is most compatible to **egrep**. The pregexp and
>   byte-pregexp procedures produce a regexp value using a slightly
>   different syntax of regular expressions that is more compatible with
>   **Perl**.

There is an [overall comparison](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) of different engines in Wikipedia that you may find it helpful. To find exact differences you may consider reading [Racket manual](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/regexp.html).